# Redis is not expiring keys

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I am running a cron which is setting approximate 1.5 million keys to my redis cluster in 1 minute. These keys which i am setting to have length of approximate 68 bytes. My configuration of redis cluster:

1. Number of master 2.
2. Replication factor 1.
3. Eviction Policy - **volatile-lru**.
4. Maxmemory of one node is 8 GB

Average TTL of keys is about 300 seconds. As the keys are not expiring the cluster is getting full after some time. How can we resolve this?

Comment: What happens when the cluster gets full?

Comment: @mattfreake Keys are getting evicted as per the policy. But it works with degraded performance.

Comment: when your cron-job adds the keys, is it specifying a TTL? How are you expecting them to expire?

Comment: We are setting the expiry of 15 days ( 12,96,000 seconds) on the cron keys.